# How to dynamically change jQuery Datatables height

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).
I want to change the height of the table whenever a user resizes the window. I'm able to catch the window resize event which allows me to calculate the new height. How can I assign the new height to the datatable object?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var calcDataTableHeight = function() {
  return $(window).height() * 55 / 100;
};

var oTable = $('#reqAllRequestsTable').dataTable({
  "sScrollY": calcDataTableHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
  oSettings.oScroll.sY = calcDataTableHeight(); 
  oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

Comment: @paul: when we resize browser window datatable  will automatically change height to browser height.

Comment: @Raje I know how the code works. I just don't know why he's multiplying by 55/100. Seems like a random number selected for a particular page - not something you would recommend as part of a general solution.

Comment: @paul I think it's just an example value given the fact the OP wants to resize his tables with regards to the window.

Comment: @Anzeo Yea, I agree. I used a different value in my implementation. I also used the smartresize option shown in rynop's answer below, which is a more up-to-date answer.

Comment: @paul Agreed, I also used rynop's answer instead of the accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

The current answer didn't work for me (using v 1.9.1).  I think this solution not only works but will perform better ([and is based on the author's suggestion](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2996/how-to-adjust-sscrolly-with-respect-to-parent-container/p1)). This example is using [smartresize](http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/) to solve cross browser window re-size issues.

```
var defaultOptions = {...};//your options
var calcDataTableHeight = function() {
    //TODO: could get crazy here and compute (parent)-(thead+tfoot)
    var h = Math.floor($(window).height()*55/100);
    return h + 'px';
};

defaultOptions.sScrollY = calcDataTableHeight();

var oTable = this.dataTable(defaultOptions);

$(window).smartresize(function(){  
    $('div.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height',calcDataTableHeight());
    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```

Comment: I use the Scroller extension and setting the height via CSS gets reset when you scroll, so this approach doesn't work. The accepted answer worked for me with 1.10.0 beta 2 though.

Answer (score 5):

Using newer versions of Datatables, there's other methods, which, when combined with the judicious use of a timer for watching the resize event triggers, works pretty well. I've left the "ancient" "window.location.reload()" line in for those who are stuck running older versions of DataTables - simply uncomment it and comment out the "table.draw()" call.

Side note, the documentation says the correct call is "table.Draw()" - that is not the case on the version I am using (call is all lowercase).

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) 
{
  if (typeof resizeTimer !== 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  }
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() 
  { 

    // Get table context (change "TABLENAME" as required)
       var table = $('#TABLENAME').DataTable();                                 

    // Set new size to height -100px
       $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', window.innerHeight-100+"px");      

    // Force table redraw
       table.draw();        

    // Only necessary for ancient versions of DataTables - use INSTEAD of table.draw()
       // window.location.reload();
  }, 250);    // Timer value for checking resize event start/stop
});
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the right answer f or DataTables 1.10.X. The only thing missing is to make the Scroller plugin aware of the height change.

Comment: If using Scroller, instead of `table.draw()` one needs to call `table.scroller.measure(true)`.

Comment: @ypnos, thanks, I'm trying that out on one of our deployments (where IE has a recalculation issue with the code) and will update.

Comment: This works almost perfectly in 1.10.X. The only thing I would wrap the `clearTimeout(resizeTimer)` statement with `if (typeof resizeTimer !== 'undefined') {` to avoid a JS error.

Comment: @lodb awesome suggestion. Feel free to modify if you want.

Answer (score 5):

**For DataTables 1.10**:

```
            $("#table").DataTable( {
              scrollY: '250px',
              scrollCollapse: true,
              paging: false,
            });

            $('#table').closest('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('max-height', '500px');
            $('#table').DataTable().draw();
```

When you changed CSS you must call `draw()`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put it like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
   "sScrollY": "auto"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dataTable1').dataTable({
                "scrollY": 150,
                "scrollX": 150
            });
            $('.dataTables_scrollBody').height('650px');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution as [documented here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_dynamic.html)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            scrollY:        '50vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging:         false
        });
    });
```

> vh    Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

You can use the [vh unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) to set a height that varies based on the size of the window.

Supported in: Chrome 20.0+, IE 9.0+, FireFox 19.0+, Safari 6.0+, Opera 20.0+

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can improve my answer?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can change the height of the table by css

```
$(window).resize(function(){
       $('#yourtable').css('height', '100px');
});
```

Comment: this won't work, it's in the datatables settings, you can't just change the table height.